# Macro to Filter Multiple Column and between Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have table like this

[image]

and i want to filter base on this criteria

1. VAlue = between 2000 and 3000
2. Status = 'FALSE'

become like this, the filter on Column F & G

[image]

and this is my code

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, Hide, popup  As Long
Dim message  As String
Dim LRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
   Columns("O:R").EntireColumn.Delete
    Range("O:R").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("F1").Value = "PO sTATUS"
    Range("G1").Value = "Value"

Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



With sht.Range("F1:F" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=B1"
   .Value = .Value
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="FALSE"
  End With

With sht.Range("G1:G" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=D1"
   .Value = .Value
 .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=2000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=3000"

   End With
```

and this code always show only Row 1 no values
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use the built-in filter functionality that Excel provides?

Comment: Because You choose `field:=1`, so it means that You want to filter Vendor?

Comment: @braX i use macro because i have huge data and many rows, and data always change every 7 hours, the data from pivot SSAS

Comment: In that case you will find that the VBA will run a LOT more slowly.

Comment: @Teamothy  i just need to filter the  status and value, i use field:=1 because i already state range with this state With sht.Range("F1:F" & LastRow)

Comment: @braX no problem with that case,  i just wondering how to solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be that You select with `With` whole table range - from column A to G to the lastRow and then filter field 6 and 7?

Comment: @teamothy 's solution should work, I`m not sure it is possible to apply autofilters like that. Excel gets confused when you tell it to apply it in one column and then another. f8'ing thru your code I can see that excel does something, just not something useful. I would just add another with statement? (see my attempt at an answer.) Not sure that is the most efficient way tho. Arent you already using power pivot? that should be the fastest method. A pivot table / slicer should be second fastest? Anywho, vba attempt in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the filter all at once?

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, Hide, popup  As Long
Dim message  As String
Dim LRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Columns("O:R").EntireColumn.Delete
    Range("O:R").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("F1").Value = "PO sTATUS"
    Range("G1").Value = "Value"

Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With sht.Range("F1:F" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=B1"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With sht.Range("G1:G" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=D1"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With sht.Range("F1:G" & LastRow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="FALSE"
    .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=2000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=3000"
End With
```

Comment: thanks mate, yes i want to filter all at once, i've been stuck with this filter. your code works fine thanks